# Android mvvm architecture trouble understanding process flow

Tags: java, android, mvvm, viewmodel, dao

I am learning about implementing MVVM architecture in android and I have trouble understanding the process flow. I cannot understand how the `dao` class is connected to the database class and how the `POJO` from the model class is added to the database.

Here is what I have I understood.

1. `Model class`:
   It is a POJO class which holds the folder structure.
2. `Dao`
   It holds all the CRUD operations that needs to be performed on the db with a method attached to them through which they can be called.
3. `Database class`
   It extends RoomDatabase and creates and returns a db instance. It also holds an abstract method which returns the Dao.

Here is my code (I actually have more, but I have provided only the area I lack understanding):

1. Model class

`    @Entity

```
public class InventoryModel {

@PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true)
public int id;
private String itemName;
private int itemQuantity;
private double itemPrice;

public InventoryModel(String itemName, int itemQuantity, double itemPrice){
    this.itemName = itemName;
    this.itemQuantity = itemQuantity;
    this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
}
```

2.Dao

```
@Dao
public interface InventoryModelDao {

@Query("SELECT * FROM InventoryModel")
LiveData<List<InventoryModel>> getAllInventoryItems();

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.ABORT)
void addItem(InventoryModel inventoryModel);

 @Delete
void deleteItem(InventoryModel inventoryModel);
}
```

3.Database class (I have only included the abstract method. the excluded part returns an instance of db)

`public abstract InventoryModelDao inventoryModelDao();`

How exactly does the `Dao` connect to the `database`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Data access object generates a lot of boilerplate code for us underneath when we specify things such as `@Delete`, `@Insert` and `@Query` operations and you won't ever see this generated code, but internally these methods are converted to methods which execute on the database itself.

The `Dao` is therefore the operations which execute on your database through generated code internally

Answer (score 1):

To extend a_local_nobody's answer. You can find the generated classes under `app\build\generated\source\apt\debug\PACKAGE\dao\InventoryModelDao_Impl`